# JPA and SQL Server replication issue - Id's conflict

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jpa, replication

I'm having the following issue with a SQL Server replicated database (Database A and Database B) and JPA. In the code I have something like this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj.setName("Nico");
objFacade.create(obj);
```

The object is persisted in database B with ID 50000, and it's replied to database A with ID 1 (it's done by SQL Server). The problem is that when I use the same object, for example:

```
obj.getId() // returns 1, should be 50000
```

It returns object's ID from database A, which JPA is unable to find becouse it's connected to database B.

The Id in the Entity is configured like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

To temporarily resolve the issue, after I persist the object I run a select to bring the right object from the database.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is persistence.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PU-sistemas" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>JNDI_SOS_Sistemas</jta-data-source>
<!-- Here I put all the classes of this database -->
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="PU-municipalidad" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>JNDI_SOS_Municipalidad</jta-data-source>
<!-- Here I put all the classes of this database -->
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: can you provide more details, persistence xml, replication code..

Comment: @KhalilM I don't handle the replication stuff but it's done by SQL Server Management Studio. I've added persistence.xml's code in my question. Thanks